# How to choose the appropriate jBPM Runtime strategies

Tags: jbpm

From what I've read so far, I can not understand what is the difference between PER_REQUEST and PER_PROCESS.

Thanks,
Eliezer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is for Per Process Instance the session information is created per each process instance and

for Per Request, no session information is stored in the database. Means a new ksession and task service instances will be returned for every invocation of the getRuntimeEngine(Context) method

Please refer JAVA Docs for more information

[JAVA docs](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.4.1.Final/kie-api-javadoc/org/kie/api/runtime/manager/RuntimeManager.html)